# Apple numeric keyboard

Tags: keyboard

When I hit the left shift key the result is a capital W.

When I click the w without the shift key I get a capital W as well.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you have some compressed air in a can, give the keys a good blast. Also, turn the keyboard upside down, hold it an at angle, and tap a corner, or a short edge, against a hard surface. This will dislodge any cruft that may have accumulated under the keys. I can't guarantee this'll fix the odd 'W' problem, but at least you'll be surprised at the amount of stuff that can accumulate.

Answer (score 1):

What's the chance of you trying another keyboard first? I would only recommend a method of fixing once you had isolated the cause.

Comment: Used a wireless and it just works fine. It seems that are many issues with the numeric type. I tried various setting but to no avail.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the specific keyboard but this is not a problem I have ever had with Apple numeric keyboards. Is this the only problem? No other letters capitalised?  Cleaning is the best idea but also you can remove the W key and you will probably find something lodged underneath.

Comment: I think it's had liquid spilt on it and its affecting the electrical paths. It may be possible to disassemble but personally I would buy another.